# I want to arrange database elements into tabular form

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, html-table

I create table like this:

```
id | a1 | a2 | a3 |  a | a4 | a5 | a6
 1 |  3 |  1 |  7 | 63 |  3 |  5 |  0
 2 |  3 |  1 |  7 | 35 |  3 |  5 |  0
 3 |  3 |  1 |  7 | 40 |  3 |  5 |  0
 4 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 00 |  0 |  0 |  0
 5 |  1 |  5 |  5 | 44 |  2 |  2 |  2
 6 |  5 |  6 |  9 | 07 |  5 |  5 |  7
 7 |  5 |  6 |  9 | 07 |  5 |  5 |  7
 8 |  1 |  5 |  0 | 64 |  2 |  5 |  7
 9 |  5 |  6 |  7 | 84 |  1 |  3 |  0
10 |  1 |  2 |  4 | 74 |  1 |  3 |  0
11 |  4 |  5 |  0 | 96 |  1 |  2 |  3
```

I want to show this data on my relevant page. The format for the page should be like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th> a1 </br> a2 </br> a3</th>
<th> a </th>
<th> a4 </br> a5 </br> a6 </th>
.
.
.
.


</tr>
</table>
```

and after 7 columns from database or we can say after id divisible by 7, it should add `</tr><tr>` tag

Currently I am using:

```
<table width="40%" border="1" align="center" bordercolor="#000000" bgcolor="#99CC99">
<?php

$x=mysql_connect("localhost","dbuser","password");
if(!$x)
{
die("not connected");
}
mysql_select_db("mydb");
$q=mysql_query("select * from table");
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{?>
<td> <?php echo $r["a1"];?></br>

<?php echo $r["a2"];?></br>

<?php echo $r["a3"];?></td>

<td><?php echo $r["a"];?></td>

<td><?php echo $r["a4"];?></br>

<?php echo $r["a5"];?></br>

<?php echo $r["a6"];?></td>  


<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

but it does not break row after 7 columns element

Comment: The result is pretty cool, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying this

```
<table width="40%" border="1" align="center" bordercolor="#000000" bgcolor="#99CC99"><tr>
<?php
$inr=0;
$x=mysql_connect("localhost","dbuser","password");
if(!$x)
{
die("not connected");
}
mysql_select_db("mydb");
$q=mysql_query("select * from table");
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{?>
<td> <?php echo $r["a1"];?></br>

<?php echo $r["a2"];?></br>

<?php echo $r["a3"];?></td>

<td><?php echo $r["a"];?></td>

<td><?php echo $r["a4"];?></br>

<?php echo $r["a5"];?></br>

<?php echo $r["a6"];?></td>  


    <?php
$inr++;
if($inr%7==0)
echo"</tr><tr>";
    }
    ?>
   </tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $x=mysql_connect("localhost","dbuser","password");
        if(!$x)
        {
            die("not connected");
        }
        mysql_select_db("mydb");
        $q=mysql_query("select * from table");
        $markup = '<table width="40%" border="1" align="center"         while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q)) {   
        $headersPrinted = false;
bordercolor="#000000" bgcolor="#99CC99"><tr>
    ';
            while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
                if (!$headersPrinted) {
                    foreach ($q as $key => $value) {
                        $markup .= "<th>$key</th>";
                    }
                    $markup .= "<tr>$markup</tr>";
                    $headersPrinted = true;
                }
                $markup .= '<tr>';
                foreach ($q as $key => $value) {
                    $markup .= "<td>$value</td>";
                }
                $markup = $markup. '</tr>';
            }
            $markup .= '</table>';

        echo $markup;
```

You should abort the printing of any HTML code before checking if you got a db connection.